# React-Native-Firebase: App store not opening when app is not installed on iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Using the [React-Native-Firebase Dynamic Links](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage) library, I followed the tutorial mentioned [here](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage#firebase-setup) and then I create a Dynamic Link using the following code:

```
const link = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
  link: "https://myInternalDomainLink.app",
  domainUriPrefix: "https://myFirebaseDynamicLink.app",
  android: {
    packageName: "sample.app"
  },
  ios: {
    bundleId: "sample.app"
  },
  analytics: {
    campaign: "banner",
  },
});
```

When the app is installed on the device, clicking on the link opens the app. That's proper. But if the app is not installed, clicking on the `Open` button in the browser preview does not open the app store, but instead navigates to the `link` parameter in the code above.

How can I make the dynamic link which is opened in the browser, to open the app in the App Store instead of navigating to my site's URL?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. You have to mention the appStoreId of your iOS app in the `ios` section in the code for creating a dynamic link:

```
const link = await dynamicLinks().buildLink({
  link: "https://myInternalDomainLink.app",
  domainUriPrefix: "https://myFirebaseDynamicLink.app",
  android: {
    packageName: "sample.app"
  },
  ios: {
    bundleId: "sample.app",
    appStoreId: "123456789" // This is the fix
  },
  analytics: {
    campaign: "banner"
  },
});
```